# How to select multiple columns but group by only one column in Hypersql database(HSQLDB)?

Tags: java, mysql, hsqldb, hypersql

I am using `HSQLDB-2.3.3` version,
here I'm showing a simple MySQL query.

Example:

```
SELECT name,age,emailid,country FROM players GROUP BY country;
```

But if I do same query in `HyperSQL` it shows an error,
`"Expression not in aggregate or group by columns PUBLIC.PLAYERS.NAME"`

And if I apply group to every column that I selected with `select` statement, it display results with aggregation of all column.

My question is, how to display multiple columns with one column aggregate (`GROUP BY`) in `HyperSQL` ??

Table `Players`:

`pid`   `name`  `emailid`   `country`       `region`        `age`

`1` `Samual`    `Samual@gmail.com`  `INDIA`     `DELHI`     `25`

`2` `Vino`  `Vino@gmail.com`        `INDIA`     `DELHI`     `20`

`3` `John`  `John@gmail.com`        `INDIA`     `DELHI`     `20`

`4` `Andy`  `Andy@gmail.com`        `INDIA`     `DELHI`     `22`

`5` `Brian` `Brian@hotmail.com` `America`       `DELHI`     `21`

`6` `Dew`       `Dew@hotmail.com`       `America`       `DELHI`     `24`

`7` `Kris`  `Kris@hotmail.com`  `America`       `DELHI`     `25`

`8` `William`   `William@hotmail.com`   `INDIA`     `DELHI`     `26`

`9` `George`    `George@hotmail.com`    `INDIA`     `DELHI`     `23`

`10`    `Peter` `Peter@gmail.com`       `INDIA`     `DELHI`     `19`

`11`    `Tom`       `Tom@gmail.com`     `America`       `DELHI`     `20`

`12`    `Andre` `Andre@hotmail.com` `INDIA`     `DELHI`     `20`

Expected `Result`:

`name`  `age`       `emailid`               `country`

`Brian` `21`        `Brian@hotmail.com` `America`

`Samual`    `25`        `Samual@gmail.com`  `INDIA`

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected result. For example if two different people are in the same country, what data do you want to return in the grouped row for that country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of GORUP BY in MySQL is different from other databases that follow the SQL Standard. In this case, the query shouldn't work.

The result that you expect contains the person with the lowest `pid` for each country. You can write a query that explicitly asks for this:

```
SELECT name, age, emailid, country FROM players 
    WHERE pid IN (SELECT MIN(pid) FROM players GROUP BY country)
```

The query first finds the lowest `pid` for each country. It then selects the two rows that contain these `pid` values.